# popen - immediate EOF after fgets

Tags: c++, c, posix

I am having troubles with popen (I am using this on a CentOS machine).

The code is like so (_oss is an ostringstream):

```
  ...

  FILE*  lp_pipe = popen("/opt/scripts/myscript.php", "r");

  if(!lp_pipe) {
    return false;
  } 

  char l_buffer[256];
  while(!feof(lp_pipe))
  {  
    if(fgets(l_buffer, 256, lp_pipe) != NULL) 
      _oss << l_buffer;
  }

  pclose(lp_pipe);

  ....
```

Now this was working fine until someone changed the php script. When I run the script from the commandline I still see the expected result, however the code doesn't work anymore. The first time `fgets` is called it now returns NULL and afterwards `feof(lp_pipe)` returns 1

Comment: Maybe the script was changed so it's writing to stderr insted of stdout?

Comment: I am no expert in php .. all I can see is that it calls "echo" ... would using 2>&1 in the popen call include stderr?

Comment: I doubt it would. Before I worried, I'd test on the command line to see if it's writing to stdout, stderr, or both.

Comment: Looking again, I wonder if the problem isn't that somebody removed the lines from the beginning of the script to say that it needs to invoke the PHP executable to run the script.

Comment: I found out what it was. My nice colleague changed the file permissions for the php file. I could read it (from the commandline) but the C++ program I built couldn't. I am sorry to have troubled you but thanks for thinking!